# Display which areas are available in a booking system php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm really struggling with some php code. It's for an assignment at university. I'm designing a booking system for vip areas within a nightclub. I want to be able to show the available areas in a table so then I can select that area and proceed to book that area for the date searched.

Basically I've managed to write some code and I think I'm getting there but I'm just a little stuck now. I've attached the `availablebooking.php` file which I want to be able to pull the areas from the database that aren't currently booked for the date searched. What I've tried to do is pull the `area_id` and `room_name` where the `area_id` is not in the booking table on the date searched, resulting in the areas that are displayed all being available. But the code I've managed to write displays the opposite, so it displays the rooms that are booked, not the rooms that are available.

Just looking for some guidance.

## availablebooking.php

```
$Criteria = $_POST ['criteria'];
$query = "SELECT Area.Area_id, Room.Room_name FROM Booking_details 
        INNER JOIN Area ON Area.Area_id=Booking_details.Area_id
        INNER JOIN Room ON Room.Room_id=Area.Room_id 
        INNER JOIN Booking ON Booking_details.Booking_id=Booking.Booking_id 
        WHERE Booking.Date != $Criteria";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die("Error getting data");

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th> Area</th> <th> Room </th>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['Area_id'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Room_name'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}
```

Comment: Try switching to a left join on Booking, adding  " and Booking.Date is NULL" to the where clause

Comment: Thank you @dbinns66 but it's not resolved it, as it just displays the tables but with no data. I want it to be able to show me all the areas that are available for the search date (the search date is using a form in a html file)
            
<input class='text-black'type="text" name="criteria" />

Comment: In addition to points made above, Dates normally need to be enclosed within inverted commas.

Comment: try posting creates and inserts for sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ it would help to see the actual schema and data

Comment: I cleaned your question up a bit and removed some of the "friendly banter". While being personable is a good thing, you want to keep your question as concise as possible about your coding issues. Also, avoid looking for broad commentary, as overly broad questions are not considered [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT a.Area_id
        , r.Room_name 
    FROM Booking_details d
     JOIN Area a
      ON a.Area_id = d.Area_id
    JOIN Room r
      ON r.Room_id = a.Room_id 
     LEFT JOIN Booking b
     ON d.Booking_id = b.Booking_id 
    AND b.Date = '$Criteria'
    WHERE b.date IS NULL;
```

Or something like that

Comment: Now that looks kinda familiar LOL

Comment: With one important difference

Comment: = just caught it... nice... I usually like to do as much "where" on the joins... very nice indeed!